# Prove that $W$ is a subspace of $K^m$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I am currently stuck with this problem:

Let $\mathbb K$ be a field and let $A \in M_{mn}({\mathbb K})$ be a matrix.

$$W = \{w \in {\mathbb K}^m | there \ is\ one\ x\in {\mathbb K}^n \ with\ Ax=w\}$$

Prove that $W$ is a subspace of ${\mathbb K}^m$.

So I have gotten as far as to understand that I have to check for the three axioms of a subspace, but in this particular case I have no clue how to get started with it. Also, I should mention that my uni gave me a solution for this question, but looking at it doesn't really get me anywhere in terms of understanding...

Any hints on how to best approach this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: In English, "field" is more idiomatic than "body". This is just the fact that the image of a linear map is a subspace of the codomain.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown thank you for the correction!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes you have to check the three properties for a linear subspace:

1. $0 \in W$
2. $w_1 \in W, w_2 \in W \implies w_1+w_2 \in W$
3. $w_1 \in W, c \in \mathbb{K} \implies cw_1\in W$

all three are satisfied in this case, infact:

1. $Ax=0$ for $x=0$ that is unique in $\mathbb{K}^n$
2. $Ax_1=w_1$ and $Ax_2=w_2$ $\implies A(x_1+x_2)=Ax_1+Ax_2=w_1+w_2$
3. $Ax_1=w_1$ and $c \in \mathbb{K}$ $\implies A(cx_1)=cA(x_1)=cw_1$ $\square$

Comment: Would you mind elaborating a bit? I don’t understand why this is the prove for the three properties... thank you for your help!

Comment: I've added a complete solution to the answer :)

Comment: Thanks! I still have a bit of an issue with coming up with these solutions myself... Is there a good way to practice this, or is it literally just "doing it until I can do it"?

Comment: you have to practice with a lot of problems also to understand the theory deeply